# addEventListener does not work on "textarea" or "body"

Tags: javascript, html

While I'm writing a `detect()` function for objects, which the user would get a `console.log` message when they either `mouseover` or `click` an element. I got stuck at adding `onclick` and `onmouseover` for two elements (or more, but I can't see) : `textarea`, and `body`.

The element that works well is `label`. When I click it or mouseover it, I get a `console.log` message.

Here is my Code :

```
function $count(string){
    count = count + 1;
    if(count <= 9999){
        if(count <= 999){
            if(count <= 99){
                if(count <= 9){
                    $log("0000" + String(count) + " : " + string);
                }else{
                    $log("000" + String(count) + " : " + string);
                }
            }else{
                $log("00" + String(count) + " : " + string);
            }
        }else{
            $log("0" + String(count) + " : " + string);
        }
    }else{
        $log(String(count) + " : " + string);
    }
}

function $detect(obj, type, script){
    if(obj.addEventListener){
        obj.addEventListener(type, script, false);
    }else{
        if(window.attachEvent){
            window.attachEvent('on' + type, script);
        }else{
            console.log("Neither window.addEventListener nor window.attachEvent is working.");
        }
    }
}

Object.prototype.listen = function(){
    if(typeof(this) == "object"){
        if(this.constructor == Array){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
                $detect(this[i], 'click', $count(this[i] + " EVENT : onclick"));
                $detect(this[i], 'mouseover', $count(this[i] + " EVENT : onmouseover"));
            }
        }else{
            if(isElement(this)){
                $detect(this, 'click', $count(this + " EVENT : onclick"));
                $detect(this, 'mouseover', $count(this + " EVENT : onmouseover"));
            }else{
                console.log("ERROR : this.constructor is not 'Object' or 'Array'.");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log("ERROR : typeof(this) is not 'Object'.");
        return null;
    }
    return this;
};
```

When I perform this action :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].listen();
```

I was willing to receive a `console.log` when I click it or move the mouse above it. However, when I click the `textarea`, it doesn't produce the `console.log`.

I guess the problem is at the `detect()` or `listen()`.

However I did not want to use `element.onclick = function(){};` because it will cover the original function, and I cannot add another onclick to it, so using `addEventListener` should be better.

Where, or which part, should I change my code?

Comment: the element and event you are not passing on `detect()` function `document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].detect();`

Comment: @SumanBogati sorry there is a typo. It should be `listen()` instead of `detect()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at the `listen()` part :

```
//...
$detect(this, "click", $count("blahblahblah");
```

I need to wrap `$count("blahblahblah")` in `function(){` `}`.
That's the problem. That's all.